# How to pass a list of numpy ndarrays as a vector to cython

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, cython

How can I pass a list of numpy ndarrays to cython? Let's say all of the elements of the list `l` (defined below) are 2d float arrays, but they may have different number of rows and columns, so I can't stack them all into a single numpy array.

`l = [np.zeros(i, 2 * i) for i in [5, 6, 7]]`

I was able to pass a list of integers to cython by using `vector[np.int_t]` as the argument of a function, but I was not successful in passing a list of ndarrays by using either `vector[np.ndarray]` or `vector[np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2]]`

Comment: From the docs: 'Also, the Python types list, dict, tuple, etc. may be used for static typing, as well as any user defined extension types.'  So you can pass it in as a `list`, and then use `list` syntax (`[]`,'for in`) to pass its items to `C` variables or structures.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with a `vector` of ndarray pointers?

Comment: @hpaulj, I would like to gain some speedup. As I understand iterating over a list is much slower.

Comment: You many need to give us more sample code, both of the list of ints case that works, and what fails with the list of arrays.

Comment: @user1210230 did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @hpaulj, you can pass the list as a declared input parameter, and then declare a buffer that will "receive" each element of your list. In this way you can iterate over the list and over the arrays with maximized efficiency. This can be coded as something like:

```
def test(list list_of_2darrays):
    cdef np.ndarray[ndim=2, dtype=np.float64_t] buff2d # check your dtype
    cdef int i, j

    for buff2d in list_of_2darrays:
        for i in range(buff2d.shape[0]):
            for j in range(buff2d.shape[1]):
                buff2d[i, j] += i + j
```